# Generating EAN-13 barcode on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, barcode, zxing, barcode-printing

I am tryint to generate an EAN-13 barcode in blackberry 5 sdk.I know I can do this in Blackberry 6.0 but I can not use ByteMatrix in 5.0, can you help me or give me an example about how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZXing is an open source project. You can copy the classes you need, or if it is too messy, just download the packages you need from the library and refactor them so that the package names do not collide with the Zxing ones already in blackberry 6.0.

Comment: can you provide a link to download those packages?

Comment: " do not collide with the Zxing ones already in blackberry 5.0." .did you mean 6.0?